# Normalize all objects scale and rotation transforms

Tags: transforms

I have an imported .blend file, and some of the objects in the file look the same but have different scales and rotations. When I clear transform the objects wheels, frame, etc. (it's a bicycle) don't fit anymore. So my question is:

"Is there a way to make the objects vertices locations match the mesh's vertices locations i.e. make it look the same even when scale is cleared?"

before clear scale
[image]

After clear scale
[image]

Comment: Can you add more info/screenshots/a .blend file?

Comment: Don't clear the rotations and scales, apply them instead. Use Ctrl A > Apply Rotation and Scale. Don't apply position as it will remove any meaningful center you objects might have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems there is parented objects to empties.

Select all objects

Alt+P > Clear and Keep Transformation

U > Object & Data (this is for linked duplicates)

Ctrl+A > Rotation & Scale

Comment: Worked! It seems that all I needed to do was the last step "Ctrl+A > Rotation and Scale"